# Science Fiction Magazine Cover Art: Danse Macabre/Skeleton and Maiden (perhaps Aboriginal?)

Tags: cover-art

Hopefully cover art questions are in-order. My recall is of art accompanying an SF magazine, perhaps Aboriginal, of a 'maiden', perhaps with flower wreath, embraced by / intertwined with a skeleton. I believe the woman was facing the viewer and apparently unaware of the skeleton. Not exactly danse macabre, but in that direction. Not, I'll add, Aboriginal 49/50 (double issue), which *also* has a theme of the danse macabre with zombie-like characters. This was likely somewhere in the mid-80's to mid-90's.

Comment: 1) Is this a full-colour illustration?  2) Are you _sure_ it's a cover, and not interior art?  3) How were the figures posed?  (e.g. standing, waist up / reclining, full body)  You can see the covers of nearly every SF magazine at [Galactic Central](http://www.philsp.com/sfi2.html).  I took a look at *Aboriginal*, *Interzone*, *F&SF*, *Amazing*, *Weird Tales*, even a few minor ones like *Cemetery Dance*, and just to be complete, *Analog* and *Asimov's*.  No luck.